# How can I create an year list for blog in drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am a newbie in drupal.

How can i create a year listing of hyperlinks like this :

2012
2011
2009
2008

of blog posts published within any year and then link them to a page to diplay a teaser listing of blog posts within that year

I have views module installed and using contextual filters for year. I would like to use PHP code to get result set from view in the templates.php file and pass the results to my template.

Then I need to build some url alias for diplaying the particular template .eg. site_url/blog/2012 should display my template.

Please note : I already have a template for site_url/blog as the blog landing page template

Please tell me if thats feasible and how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Drupal's built in taxonomy module for this. Go to the taxonomy page by going to `admin->structure->taxonomy`.

In there you can create a new vocabulary called Year where you can enter as many or as few years as you like.

Then in your blog post content type create a new field called year and link it to the vocabulary by selecting term reference as the type and following the instructions from there.

If you wanted you could build a module that adds new years to the vocabulary automatically but that's a whole different question.

To then show only posts with that year in you can build a view. Install the Views module and go to `structure->views` and add a new view to show content of type Blog Post. You can then set a **contextural filter** in the advanced tab to show ones tagged with the year. Then you can expose the filter so the user can change the year and you should be set.

**NOTE:** The view needs to be a page rather than a block for this to work.

Comment: Thanks, but what i was guessing is some sort of php code in a block which would figure out the entries published (if any ) in a year and then display those years sorted by recent first. Is that possible in drupal 7

Comment: thanks for the update. I also edited the question. Please check

Comment: That's how the contextual filters work. By using the URL so that would work.

Comment: You didn't give any reasoning for using Views in place of the default taxonomy term displays. I assume the reason for this was just to expose the Year filter, but that will expose a select list, not anchor elements, so you didn't give him a complete answer. The Better Exposed Filters module would allow him to change the filter to anchor elements, but even if you'd mentioned that, you should have explained why you were suggesting Views instead of the default Taxonomy displays. Using Views in this way is like using a bulldozer to hammer a nail.

Comment: It is however the accepted answer, and it works. Down voting because it's not how you would do things when it's already helped is pretty poor form.

Comment: The person asking the question doesn't know any better.. that's why he asked the question. It's up to the people who DO know better to submit answers that provide value and vote for the ones that do. A good answer would help not only the original person who asked the question but anyone else who has the same question later on. Yours doesn't. And instead of editing it to improve its quality, you argue that its poor quality doesn't matter. How does that help anyone?

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you. It's clearly helped the OP. If anyone else reads this question and uses your approach then fair enough.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the Taxonomy module creates a teaser listing for all nodes associated with a term. So if you create a Blog Year vocabulary and attach it to the blog node type using a term reference field, Taxonomy will automatically create a paged display for all nodes that have the "2012" term, and for all nodes that have the "2011" term, etc. You can set up a custom path structure for these using the [pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module, which you should be using anyway.

Then all you need to do is create a block that links to each term. The [Taxonomy Block](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_block) module will do that. Or you could create a view to output these taxonomy links in a block.

If you're going to use Views, you don't necessarily need to use Taxonomy at all. Each node stores at least two date fields, both a created date and an updated date. You can easily access this in Views. Create a view of teaser displays and add the `Content: Created Year` contextual filter. Unfortunately, I don't know a good solution right now for displaying the years in Drupal 7 Views, so I'd probably write a module for that bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [DATE](http://drupal.org/project/date) module that provide also the calendar module and with views you can do whatever you want .

Answer (score 1):

You can do it all with Views, no taxonomy is needed. I'm not sure if this functionality is introduced only after the previous answers.

Have a look at Drupal's "archive' view, which is provided with views, but disabled. *Enable* it and examine it thouroughly. You should be able to sort it out based on that example.

This is what I did:

You need two views displaying all your posts. A PAGE-view and a BLOCK view. Make sure they are displayed alongside each other,on the same page.

In the PAGE view, create a contextual filter, on CONTENT: CREATED YEAR. This itself will be enough to filter your posts on a year given in the URL

In the BLOCK view, create a contextual filter, on CONTENT: CREATED YEAR. Then, you can choose:

```
When the filter value is NOT available:

• Display all results for the specified field
• Provide default value
• Hide view
X Display a summary
```